# Slim PHP: Only catch valid routes with middleware

Tags: php, slim

I'm writing a REST API with Slim. I have written a small middleware to protect the resources so only authenticated users will be able to access them:

```
<?php
class SecurityMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware
{
    protected $resource;
    public function __construct($resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }
    public function call()
    {
        //get a reference to application
        $app = $this->app;
        //skip routes that are exceptionally allowed without an access token:
        $publicRoutes = ["/","/login","/about"];
        if (in_array($app->request()->getPathInfo(),publicRoutes)){
            $this->next->call(); //let go
        } else {
            //Validate:
            if ($this->resource->isValid()){
                $this->next->call(); //validation passed, let go
            } else {
                $app->response->setStatus('403'); //validation failed
                $app->response->body(json_encode(array("Error"=>"Access token problem")));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but the undesired side effect is the middleware does not make a distinction between existing routes and non-existing routes. For example, if a the user attempts to request a route like `/dfghdfgh` which does not exist, instead of getting an HTTP status code of 404 he'll get a 403 saying there is no access token. I would like to add an implementation similar to the following check on the middleware class:

```
if ($app->hasRoute($app->request->getPathInfo()){
    $this->next->call(); //let go so user gets 404 from the app.
}
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 6):

I use a [hook](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Hooks-Overview) to do what you're trying to do, as MamaWalter suggested, but you want to use `slim.before.dispatch` rather than an earlier hook.  If the route your user is trying to visit doesn't exist, the hook will never be called and the `404` gets thrown.

I'm doing exactly that in my own [Authorization Middleware](https://github.com/jeremykendall/slim-auth/blob/71fa520af157e813ce84440321fe6c0ef5f2b317/src/JeremyKendall/Slim/Auth/Middleware/Authorization.php).  Works like a charm.

Comment: i just realized that you wrote the tutorial that i followed and my example is based on your work :) Nice work, really helpful ... sorry i should mention it.

Comment: That's awesome! I thought it looked familiar.  I figured it was just a case of great minds thinking alike :-)  Looks like I need to update the method's docblock to change the recommended hook.

Comment: Is it possible to hook only some routes to trigger middleware call()?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe my implementation will work for you:

```
<?php

class CustomAuth extends \Slim\Middleware {

    public function hasRoute() {
        $dispatched = false;

        // copied from Slim::call():1312
        $matchedRoutes = $this->app->router->getMatchedRoutes($this->app->request->getMethod(), $this->app->request->getResourceUri());
        foreach ($matchedRoutes as $route) {
            try {
                $this->app->applyHook('slim.before.dispatch');
                $dispatched = $route->dispatch();
                $this->app->applyHook('slim.after.dispatch');
                if ($dispatched) {
                    break;
                }
            } catch (\Slim\Exception\Pass $e) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        return $dispatched;
    }

    public function call() {

        if ($this->hasRoute()) {
            if ($authorized) {
                $this->next->call();
            }
            else {
                $this->permissionDenied();
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->next->call();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asking for, but personnaly when i need to check authentification on some routes i do it like this.

config:

```
$config = array(
    ...,

    'user.secured.urls' => array(
        array('path' => '/user'),
        array('path' => '/user/'),
        array('path' => '/user/.+'),
        array('path' => '/api/user/.+')
    ),
    ...

);
```

middleware:

```
/**
 * Uses 'slim.before.router' to check for authentication when visitor attempts
 * to access a secured URI.   
 */
public function call()
{
    $app = $this->app;
    $req = $app->request();
    $auth = $this->auth;
    $config = $this->config;

    $checkAuth = function () use ($app, $auth, $req, $config) {

        // User restriction
        $userSecuredUrls = isset($config['user.secured.urls']) ? $config['user.secured.urls'] : array();
        foreach ($userSecuredUrls as $url) {
            $urlPattern = '@^' . $url['path'] . '$@';
            if (preg_match($urlPattern, $req->getPathInfo()) === 1 && $auth->hasIdentity() === false) {

            $errorData = array('status' => 401,'error' => 'Permission Denied');
            $app->render('error.php', $errorData, 401);
            $app->stop();                   
        }
    }

    };

    $app->hook('slim.before.router', $checkAuth);

    $this->next->call();
}
```

but if almost all your routes need authentification maybe not the best solution.

great example: http://www.slideshare.net/jeremykendall/keeping-it-small-slim-php

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basically you're just doing the opposite: Instead of letting go of publicly available routes, you're just catching the ones that need authentication. In my case, almost all of the resources require authentication, So I don't think this approach fits my use-case.