# Slim framework restrict url

Tags: php, slim

I have my REST Base APi on Slim Framework. I will need a help in restricting some URL which should only be accessible internally and not exposed public. How can i achieve this please.

/REST/api/v1/getusers -- is publicly available

/REST/api/v1/userinfo -- new api which i want only local access i.e other systems on the network can access but not exposed publicly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slim PHP: Only catch valid routes with middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881963/slim-php-only-catch-valid-routes-with-middleware)

Comment: Maybe keep things simple and respond only if visiting/requesting IP falls into an IP-range you expect from internal network?

Comment: I think this should be specified in server's configuration files, not in `php` code

Comment: You can write a middleware to restrict these routes to specific IP Address

Answer (score 2):

Firstly add `rka-ip-address-middleware` to determine the client's IP address. You can install this using `composer require akrabat/rka-ip-address-middleware`:

```
$app->add(new RKA\Middleware\IpAddress());
```

Now, create a group and put all restricted routes inside it. You can then add middleware to the group to ensure that the client IP address is allowed before any of the routes in the group are run:

```
$app->group('', function () {
    $app->get('/REST/api/v1/userinfo', UserInfoAction::class);

    // other $app->get(), $app->post(), $app->put() etc actions here

})->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    // Only allow internal IP addresses
    $allowed = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1']; // or whatever
    $clientIp = $request->getAttribute('ip_address');

    // Is the client's IP address in the allowed list?
    if (!in_array($clientIp, $allowed)) {
        // Not allowed: return a 401 error
        return $response->withStatus(401);
    }

    // Allowed: continue to action
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a middleware for this: its name is **Slim-Restrict-Route** and you can find it [here](https://github.com/DavidePastore/Slim-Restrict-Route). It uses the `Ip` Validator of [Respect/Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/) and [rka-ip-address-middleware](https://github.com/akrabat/rka-ip-address-middleware).

You can register it in this way:

```
$app->add(new RKA\Middleware\IpAddress());

$options = array(
  'ip' => '192.*.*.*'
);

$app->get('/api/myEndPoint',function ($req, $res, $args) {
  //Your amazing route code
})->add(new \DavidePastore\Slim\RestrictRoute\RestrictRoute($options));
```